# A case of divergence theorem

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

[image]

$$\hat{n}_2=-\hat{n}_1$$

$$\iiint_D \nabla \overrightarrow{F} dV=\iiint_{D_1} \nabla \overrightarrow{F} dV+\iiint_{D_2} \nabla \overrightarrow{F} dV$$

$$\\$$

$$\iint_S \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n} d \sigma=\iint_{S_1} \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n} d \sigma+\iint_{S_2} \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n} d \sigma+\iint_K \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n}_1 d \sigma+\iint_K \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n}_2 d \sigma$$
Since $\displaystyle{\iint_K \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n}_1 d \sigma+\iint_K \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n}_2 d \sigma=0}$, because $\hat{n}_2=-\hat{n}_1$, we have that:

$$\iint_S \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n} d \sigma=\iint_{S_1} \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n} d \sigma+\iint_{S_2} \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n} d \sigma$$

---

What are $S$, $S_1$ and $S_2$??

Comment: looks like you asked the same question again lol

Comment: The diagram isn't very clear. Could you please define what all these regions and surfaces are supposed to be?

Comment: This picture is in my notes like that... And I don't understand which is meant to be $S$.. :/ Do you have any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S$ is the sphere, which is the boundary of the ball $D$.

The ball $D$ has been divided into 2 semi-balls $D_1$ and $D_2$.

The semi-ball $D_1$ is bounded by a semi-sphere $S_1$ and circle disk $K$.
Similarly $D_2$ is bounded by $S_2$ and the same circle disk $K$.

Comment: So a sphere is the boundary of a ball? That means that the ball includes also the inside part of the sphere?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The ball *is* the inside part of the sphere. A "sphere" is only the surface of the ball.

Comment: Ok!!! Thanks a lot!!! :-)